# Encapsulation with a dbParameter class

Tags: design-patterns, vb.net

I am using the DatabaseHelper class to execute SQL statements e.g. ExecuteDataReader, ExecuteDataTable etc. The signature for ExecuteReader is:

```vb
Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connectionString As String, _
                                                   ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                   ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                   ByVal ParamArray commandParameters() As DbParameter) As DbDataReader
```

Therefore it is expecing some parameters. I have created the class below:

```vb
Public Class clsParameterValues
    'Implements IDisposable

    Private paramValues(0) As DbParameter

    Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As String, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
        Dim intArrayBound As Integer

        intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
        'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
        If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
            intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
            ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
        End If

        If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

            paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
        ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
            paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
            'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
        End If
        Return intArrayBound
    End Function



Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Date, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intArrayBound As Integer

    intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
    'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
    If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
        intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
        ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
    End If

    If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

        'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, DateValue(strParameterValue))
        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
    ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, DateValue(strParameterValue))
        'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
        'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
    End If
    Return intArrayBound
End Function

Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Decimal, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intArrayBound As Integer

    intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
    'If intArrayBound > 0 Then'
    If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
        intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
        ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
    End If

    If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
    ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
        'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
        'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
    End If
    Return intArrayBound
End Function

Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Boolean, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intArrayBound As Integer

    intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
    'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
    If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
        intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
        ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
    End If

    If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
    ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
        paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
        'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
        'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
    End If
    Return intArrayBound
End Function

Public Function getParameterValues() As DbParameter()
    Return paramValues
End Function

'Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
'    Erase paramValues
'    paramValues = Nothing
'End Sub'

End Class
```

The app can use this class to create the parameter collection and then get the parameter collection before supplying it to ExecuteReader. The intDatabaseType allows this to work with SQL Server and Oracle.

Is this a reasonable approach or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

#### Potential issues

- `intDatabaseType` should be promoted to an instance variable instead of being supplied in every call to `AssignParameterValues` - the way you have it, **you can build an 5-items array with 2 parameters for SQL Server and 3 parameters for Oracle**. Not sure that's the way it was intended...
- Your "database type" is a magic number. What tells client code to pass a `1` for a SQL Server database and a `2` for an Oracle database? Nothing. Not even an exception. That parameter is literally **begging to be an enum type**.
- If `ExecuteReader` is ultimately taking in the return value from `getParameterValues`, then there's no need for `ParamArray` here; consider changing it to take any `IEnumerable(Of DbParameter)`.
- `AssignParameterValues` will resize the array even if `intDataBaseType` is an invalid value, so **the return value is meaningless**. Why are you returning the array's upper bound? Why not make it a `Sub` that can either succeed or throw an exception?
- Instead of an array of `DbParameter`, consider using a `List(Of DbParameter)`. That alone would **make all of that `ReDim Preserve` and `UBound` stuff go away**!

---

#### Naming issues

- **Hungarian notation** is outdated, ugly at best and misleading at worst. Do yourself a favor and rename those variables!

  - `clsParameterValues` => `ParameterValues`
  - `intArrayBound` => `arrayUpperBound`
  - `intDatabaseType` => `databaseType`
  - `strParameterName` => `name`
  - `strParameterValue` => `value`

---

#### Other nitpicks

- `intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1` can be shortened to `intArrayBound += 1`.
- Prefer `If Not SomeBooleanExpression Then` for negation and `If SomeBooleanExpression Then` for the opposite, instead of the redundant `If SomeBooleanExpression = True Then`.